# How to add a global carousel (owl-carousel) to apostrophe-cms?

Tags: owl-carousel, apostrophe-cms

I'm trying to add a carousel to my apostrophe site. The user should be able to add new images with page links to the carousel.

I tried to go apostrophe-pieces way but there is no such type as image.

The user should be able to add images, just like adding [a person](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/reusable-content-with-pieces.html) to the site. Then my carousel will list these images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema type for this is a `singleton`, which can then use any widget type, including the core `slideshow` widget: https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophecms/v/gitbook/tutorials/getting-started/schema-guide#singleton.

Two ways we've done a slideshow are by simply using this one slideshow schema field in a carousel widget and using an array schema with one image in each slide (especially when slides need other content like text and links).